# Can we use toString() function with stringbuffer object-'sb'?

Tags: java, string, function, tostring

This is the program to reverse a string preserving space position. In this problem with or without using `toString()` function with `sb` the output is coming right. One thing I didn't understand that `sb` is a `StringBuffer` object then how can we use the object in last print statement as the object needs to be converted to the string format.

this is a code of jdk 1.8.0

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String st="";
    st=sc.nextLine();
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(st.replace(" ",""));
    sb=sb.reverse();
    for(int i=0;i<st.length();i++)
    {
        if(st.charAt(i)==' ')
        {
            sb.insert(i,' ');
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);

}
```

Comment: Note: `StringBuffer` has all its methods `synchronized`. This is now considered unnecessary and part of a historical misassumption about how Java objects should work. `StringBuffer` was replaced by `StringBuilder` in 2004, which is non-synchronized but otherwise identical, and is therefore marginally more lightweight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrintStream` (like `System.out` or `System.err`) has several overloaded `println` methods. Here, specifically, you're calling [`println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-). This method calls `String.valueOf` on its argument and then prints it. For a non-null argument, it's equivalent to calling `toString()` on it.

Comment: Thanks for the instant response! But one thing I want to clarify that we must use sb.toString() to show it in a String format, but I am amazed to see the answer without using it. Can you explain me in a more general way?

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma `println` converts the arugment to string itself. You don't need to call `toString` yourself.

Comment: or, if you *need*  a `String` you must call `toString`, since `println` also accepts an `Object` *you* must not call it